# How to update selected Dom element with DomCrawler component of symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, dom, domcrawler

How to update selected Dom element with DomCrawler component of symfony?

```
$crawler->filter("table.positions")->addHtmlContent("<tr class="position"></td></td></tr>");

$crawler->filter('.position')->html(); // InvalidArgumentException: The current node list is empty.
```

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
$crawler->filter('.position')->getNode(0)->setAttribute('ATTR','VALUE');
```

this code get the first node matches the selector and change the value of the selected attribute.

Comment: Nope. This one doesn't work for me when I am trying to loop nodes and update needed values

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html):

> All filter methods return a new Crawler instance with filtered content.

hence

```
$populatedCrawler = $crawler->filter("table.positions")->addHtmlContent("<tr class="position"></td></td></tr>");

echo '<pre>'.$populatedCrawler->filter('.position')->html().'</pre>';
```

will give you what you expect.